# Navigate to another page and a specific element Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I wanted to navigate from one page to another page and a specific element in the other page on button click. How can i do that ?

My scenario: index.html and periodical.html are the two files, periodical.html have multiple elements. Now on click of a button in index.html, i wanted to navigate directly to a specific element in Periodical.html.I am using `$stateProvider` and `$urlRouterProvider`

My state (Working fine until navigating to periodical.html):

```
.state('page.periodical', {
                url: '/periodical',
                controller: 'PeriodicalController',
                controllerAs: 'periodical',
                templateUrl: 'app/components/page/periodical/periodical.html',
                data: {
                    pageTitle: 'Periodical page',
                    dashboard: 'periodical'
                }
        })
```

I am doing `$state.go('page.periodical');` from index.html controller which is working fine. How can i achieve `$state.go('page.periodical#rt_page_element1');` ? this is resulting in error but the element reference `#rt_page_element1` is correct.

Comment: shouldn't it be like
$state.go('page.periodical#rt_page_element1'); ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decorate `$stateProvider`

```
angular.module('app').config(['$provide', function ($provide) {

  /**
   * Extend the UI Router $stateProvider, adding the ability to specify an
   * anchor hash as a parameter in the ui-sref directive.
   */
  $provide.decorator('$state', ['$delegate', function ($stateProvider) {

    // Save the orignal function for generating a state's URL.
    var $stateHref = $stateProvider.href;

    // Create our extended function.
    $stateProvider.href = function href(stateOrName, params, options) {
      var hash = '';
      params = params || {};
      var hashParam = params['#'];

      // Check if the anchor parameter was specified.
      if (typeof hashParam !== 'undefined') {
        // Ensure hash parameter is a string and not empty.
        if ((typeof hashParam === 'string' || hashParam instanceof String) && hashParam.length) {
          hash = '#' + hashParam;
        }

        delete params['#'];
      }

      // Return the original parsed URL with the hash appended.
      return $stateHref(stateOrName, params, options) + hash;
    };

    return $stateProvider;
  }]);

}]);
```

And then

```
<a ui-sref="page.periodical({'#': IDToScrollTo })">
```

The exact solution is discribed [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/701#issuecomment-71959436)